# Algorithm for finding all permutations of a number

Tags: java, algorithm, int, permutation

I have to write a program that gives all permutatioms of a number. For example, the user enters the number 4. I have to return all possible combinations of the numbers 1,2,3,4. I am having an issue with a good method for getting all of the permutations. I have it so my program puts the number 1-n in an array. However, I cannot think of a good way of getting permutation. I know I need to use recursion, but my issue is a way to get the permutations in the first place. I know switching the number around is probably the best way to go, but what is the best method for doing that?

Comment: You may want to read Sedgewick's paper: http://homepage.math.uiowa.edu/~goodman/22m150.dir/2007/Permutation%20Generation%20Methods.pdf

Comment: Permutations are performed on sets of objects, not on single numbers.

Comment: If this is off topic as asking to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** then I, Sir, am a Dutchman.

Comment: I needed this functionality too in a project I was working on. Unfortunately I cannot post an answer here because the question has been closed. But here are links to the ideas that I used for my solution: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/240762/78044 and https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/interesting-method-generate-binary-numbers-1-n/

Answer (score 4):

We can simply use the `recursion` to get the possibilities by recursively selecting one element and then applying the recursion to the sub set of that array. this is an example for numbers 1 to 3

[image]

Comment: Why do you provide code, when the TO specifically asks just for the algorithm?

Comment: I understand why that would work extremely well for 3, however, how would it work for a larger number, such as 6 or 7? I have not learned recursion yet, so I apologize if my question seems stupid.

Comment: For better understanding of the recursion start with simple example like finding factorial of a number n

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to understand the algorithm is this. To get all the permutations of 1 to 4, you want

- 1, followed by the permutations of 2,3,4
- 2, followed by the permutations of 1,3,4
- 3, followed by the permutations of 1,2,4
- 4, followed by the permutations of 1,2,3

This is a fairly standard bit of recursion. For each number, recursively find all the permutations of the other numbers, and add this number on the beginning.

Comment: How would that work for larger numbers, such as 6 or 7 though? Wouldn't I still have the issue of finding all permutations of the numbers before that?

Comment: @ColinNull It works the same way -- the recursion takes care of finding all permutations of the other numbers.

Comment: @ColinNull: The thing to notice is that in each of the 4 cases listed above, the list of items that you still have to permute *is smaller* -- just 3 items instead of the original 4.  So how to generate each of them?  Simply call your own generate-all-permutations function with each of these smaller sets, trusting that it produces the right answer!  The only case you actually need to solve "the hard way" is the one where the set to permute has length 1 -- and then the answer is easy :)

Comment: @j_random_hacker So how would a method like permuteAll work? I see the point of recursion, but I'm still just confused on how I could get the permute all method to work?

Comment: @ColinNull: In the OP's example, it will call itself 4 times, each time with 3 numbers, and build the list of all permutations of 4 numbers exactly as he described.  Just mentally add ", which you obtained by calling yourself with that smaller set of numbers" to the end of each the bulleted lines.

Comment: @ColinNull can I suggest you start by writing a simpler recursive method to get the idea? Write a method `fact(n)` to calculate n factorial. If n is 0, then return 1; otherwise, return n*fact(n-1).

Answer (score 2):

Recursion is your friend. If you have one element, your solution is obviously [[1]]. For two elements, you can take all your "one"-solutions (well, there is only one) and stick the 2 either before or after the 1, so you get [[2,1], [1,2]]. For three elements, take all your "two" solutions and put the three in first, second or third position. From [2,1] you get [3,2,1], [2,3,1] and [2,1,3]. From [1,2] you get [3,1,2], [1,3,2] and [1,2,3]. All together, your solution is [[3,2,1], [2,3,1], [2,1,3], [3,1,2], [1,3,2], [1,2,3]].

Answer (score 0):

Notice how [chiastic-security's algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26833700/47984) for generating all permutations of n numbers relies on being able to generate all permutations of n-1 numbers?  To use his algorithm, all we need is that ability, and one more thing: a way to generate all permutations of a set containing just one number.

Generating all permutations of a single number is trivial: there's only one, consisting of just that number by itself.

What about the other requirement -- the ability to generate all permutations of n-1 numbers?  That seems harder, but it turns out not to be.  Suppose n=2 for the problem we want to solve: then n-1 = 1, and then we're OK, because we know how to generate all permutations of 1 number.  So, applying chiastic-security's algorithm here gives us a way to generate all permutations of 2 numbers.  If instead n=3 for the problem we want to solve, then n-1 = 2, and we've just established that we can generate all permutations of 2 numbers, so we're still OK -- we know how to generate all permutations of 3 numbers.  If instead n=4, then n-3 = 3, and we've just established that we can generate all permutations of 3 numbers, so we can also generate all permutations of 4 numbers.  Clearly this reasoning can continue on forever -- so you can generate all permutations of any number of numbers this way.

That reasoning is informal, but it can be made completely precise with [mathematical induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction).  If induction can be applied, then the surprising result is that we never have to solve any "big" problems "the hard way" -- we can always break them down into one or more small problems, which can in turn be broken into still smaller problems, until one or more "base cases" are reached that are easy to solve -- and then the solutions to the bigger problems can be pieced together from these solutions to the simpler subproblems.

Comment: Yes, his reasoning was good, and I understand it makes it less complicated, by making n one less. However, for a number such as 8,  which i would only need to do 7 permutations for using his logic, that still requires finding 5040 permutations, and adding the proper numbers to the beginning of each. I don't know if I'm simply over-complicating it, but I cannot think of a way to get every single possible permutation. I can't find a specific pattern for switching numbers that allows for every combination.

Comment: @ColinNull: Suppose your function is called `perm()`.  When `perm({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8})` has been called and it needs to generate all 5040 permutations of the 7-element set `{2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}`, how can it do this?  By calling `perm({2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8})`.  Simple as that!

Comment: @ColinNull: That *is* the recursion: calling "yourself" to solve smaller subproblems.

Comment: @ColinNull: I'm assuming that the difficulty you're having in this example is with how to generate the set of all 5040 permutations of `{2,3,4,5,6,7,8}`.  Once you have those permutations, you can create all 5040 permutations of `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}` *that start with 1* by putting a 1 in front of each of them.  You need to repeat the process for each of the 8 digits; after that, you will have generated all the permutations that start with 1, all the permutations that start with 2, ..., right up to 8 -- which is all the permutations there are.

Comment: So my method essentially "breaks down" a number into something I can reasonably get the permutations from,and then adds on the first number, and so on. I can continually call this method until I have all possible combinations. That's the recursion, using the same method over and over to solve the problem. Breaking it down into smaller simpler problems.

Comment: @ColinNull: Yes. But it's better here to think of it as operating on a *set of elements*, rather than on a number.  The work will need to be done by a function, let's call it `perm()`, that takes a set of numbers (the elements you want to permute), and returns a set of ordered lists of numbers (each list in this set being such a permutation).  You can then write a "front-end" function, let's call it `permsUpTo()`, which takes an integer `n`, creates the set `{1, 2, ..., n}`, and calls `perm()` with that set.